# Реализовать сгруппированный список

Tags: javascript, html, list

Подскажите, с каким образом лучше реализовать сгруппированный список в html. 
Задача такая, есть выпадающий список - необходимо сделать так что бы данные в нем были разделены **заголовками** которые фиксировались в шапке списка. Когда очередная группа была пролистана - фиксировался следующий, как в таблицах в которых при скроле заголовок оставался на месте.
[image: Визуализация задания]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял, вы хотели вот-так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<style>
  .list {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden auto;
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .list>ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .list>ul>.title {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #ccc;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .list>ul>li {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
<div class="list">
  <div>Список</div>
  <ul>
    <div class="title">Заголовок 1</div>
    <li onclick="alert('1.1');">1.1</li>
    <li onclick="alert('1.2');">1.2</li>
    <li onclick="alert('1.3');">1.3</li>
    <li onclick="alert('1.4');">1.4</li>
    <li onclick="alert('1.5');">1.5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <div class="title">Заголовок 2</div>
    <li onclick="alert('1.1');">2.1</li>
    <li onclick="alert('1.2');">2.2</li>
    <li onclick="alert('1.3');">2.3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <div class="title">Заголовок 3</div>
    <li onclick="alert('3.1');">3.1</li>
    <li onclick="alert('3.2');">3.2</li>
    <li onclick="alert('3.3');">3.3</li>
    <li onclick="alert('3.4');">3.4</li>
    <li onclick="alert('3.5');">3.5</li>
    <li onclick="alert('3.6');">3.6</li>
    <li onclick="alert('3.7');">3.7</li>
    <li onclick="alert('3.8');">3.8</li>
    <li onclick="alert('3.9');">3.9</li>
    <li onclick="alert('3.10');">3.10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Вместо alert('что-то') можно написать любой JS код. Он будет выполняться при нажатии

Comment: Надеюсь вот-так, конечно можно сделать что-бы div появлялся при нажатии куда-то, например на select, можно ещё и анимацию сделать

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [`position: sticky;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), но вроде как беда с [поддержкой](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)..

```css
.list {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}

.list > ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.list > ul > .title {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ccc;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <div class="title">- title 1</div>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <div class="title">- title 2</div>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <div class="title">- title 3</div>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Я сейчас осознал свою ошибку, я не уточнил что это должен быть выпадающий список как в первом ответе. Где заголовки фиксируются и одновременно иметь функцию выбора как во втором, через option.

Comment: @Виталий, мне кажется что подобная реализация доступна только кастомным селекторам

Answer (score 0):

Вот код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Список</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
  <body>
    <select>
      <option selected hidden>Список</option>
      <option disabled style="position:sticky;">Заголовок 1</option>
      <option>1.1</option>
      <option>1.2</option>
      <option>1.3</option>
      <option>1.4</option>
      <option>1.5</option>
      <option>1.5</option>
      <option disabled>Заголовок 2</option>
      <option>2.1</option>
      <option>2.2</option>
      <option>2.3</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Так надо?
Если что:
selected - то, что будет показываться изначально
disabled - то, что нельзя выбрать
hidden - то, чего не будет видно в списке, но если использовать с selected, то от этого будет толк (как я сделал: `<option selected hidden>Список</option>`)

Comment: Я сейчас осознал свою ошибку, я не уточнил что это должен быть выпадающий список как в первом ответе. Где заголовки фиксируются и одновременно иметь функцию выбора как во втором, через option.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас я уже сделал так, как надо